# LOAD DATA INFILE - Set Value on Count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

User's can upload a CSV and define them by their columns.
So the CSV hasn't a statick definition, but more like every user can define their CSV like they want.
Users also bought an account which is limited to a number of products they can "activate".
**Example to make things clear:**
User has an account which allows him to activate 1000 products.
But in his CSV which he is uploading, he set 1100 products to active.
We load this CSV into our MYSQL-DB with an `LOAD DATA INFILE` Query.

To avoid this behavior that a user can activate more products by CSV then his account is even limited to - is there any possible solution to say, like:

```
active = IF(@active = 1 AND COUNTER <= 1000, (1 AND COUNTER++), 0 )
```

Comment: Upload into a temporary table, then only insert the desired records (e.g. by applying a `LIMIT` clause) into the final table.

Comment: Ohhh my god of course. We are even pushing the CSV before it comes to the PRODUCTION-Table into a TMP-Table. God so clear. Thank a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it und came up with the following solution - inspired by eggyal's comment.
I know this problem is highly individual, but if you abstract it ( as i will try to abstract my answer ) it will be maybe helpfull for other or similar problems with `LOAD DATA INFILE` Querys.
**1) Load the CSV-Values into an temporary table.**
*In some cases this will be enough to modify several values.

In my probelm it wasn't cause it was important, how many products will be active after everything is in the final table.

The active values can change, products which are active in the final table will be set to inactive by the CSV, so you can't be sure about the final sum of active products after you loaded the hole CSV into your final table. So move on to step 2. ( Also if you allready modified your values in step 1)*
**2) Push the CSV-Values loaded into `table_tmp` to your `table_final`**
This query example may help you:

```
UPDATE 
table_final, table_tmp
SET 
table_final.value1 = table_tmp.value1,
table_final.value2 = table_tmp.value2
WHERE 
table_final.some_key = table_tmp.some_key
```

**3) Now cut the things, which are over the limit**
I did this by an `UPDATE`-Query with an `LIMIT`-Param.
**4) Delete the rows in `table_final`**

**FINAL THOUGHTS**:
A Problem i discovered is, that you can't put the values buck in order to the order of the user's CSV.
If i wan't to start by setting back the "active"-value for these products which were last in the CSV, i am kind of lost, because i cant get back this order.
If you know a way to restore this order, - or you come up with even an better solution - please let us know ;)